# Returning Int from If statement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make an int equal to a  certain value if a condition is true.
I'm having trouble getting the bloodtype int from the if statement so it can be applied to my class. I know its probably a simple solution but my brain is fried.

```
 private void btnAddPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)////Add Patients
    {
        string name = txtPatientName.Text;
        int bloodType,age=30;           
        DateTime dob;
        bool bloodA = rbA.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodB = rbB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodAB = rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool blood0 = rb0.IsChecked.Equals(true);




        // if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == ""||bloodType==0)
        if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == "" || !bloodA || !bloodAB || !bloodB || !blood0)
        {

            if (txtPatientName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Patient's Name");
            }

            else if (!bloodA || !bloodAB || !bloodB || !blood0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
            }

            //else if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Please select a date");
            //}

        }

        else
       if (bloodA)
        {
            bloodType = 0;

        }
        else if (bloodB)
        {
            bloodType = 1;
        }
        else if (bloodAB)
        {
            bloodType = 2;
        }
        else {             
            bloodType = 3;           

            dob = dpDOB.SelectedDate.Value;

            Patient patient= new Patient(name, age, bloodType);///cant get bloodtype value

            MainWindow mainWindow = Owner as MainWindow;

           patients.Add(patient);
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = null;
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = patients;
            // this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: when it is within the method it is a local variable in the method. declare it as a field or property outside of the method and it will be available to the rest of the class

Comment: You're only creating and adding a patient to the `patients` if `bloodType` equals 3. The last else statement should only contain `bloodType = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
int bloodtype = -1;
```

(or some other value you won't use otherwise).  the variable only gets set inside the `if else` statements, so you can't send it to your `Patient` class since it doesn't equal anything outside of the conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

The place you want the bloodType will only be evaluated if all other conditions fails as you use a if else if structure. Futhermore, you assign it to 3 prior passing it to the constructor of Patient. Therefore, at the moment this code is evaluated, bloodType will be equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your bloodType condition and also take your patient creation out from the blood type 3 check block:

```
private void btnAddPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)////Add Patients
{
    string name = txtPatientName.Text;
    int bloodType,age=30;           
    DateTime dob;
    bool bloodA = rbA.IsChecked.Equals(true);
    bool bloodB = rbB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
    bool bloodAB = rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
    bool blood0 = rb0.IsChecked.Equals(true);


    var bloodTypeDefined = bloodA || bloodAB || bloodB || blood0;

    // if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == ""||bloodType==0)
    if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == "" || !bloodTypeDefined)
    {

        if (txtPatientName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Patient's Name");
        }

        else if (!bloodTypeDefined)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
        }

        //else if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Please select a date");
        //}

    }

    else
    {
       if (bloodA) bloodType = 0;
       else if (bloodB) bloodType = 1;
        else if (bloodAB) bloodType = 2;
        else bloodType = 3;           

        dob = dpDOB.SelectedDate.Value;

        Patient patient= new Patient(name, age, bloodType);///cant get bloodtype value

        MainWindow mainWindow = Owner as MainWindow;

       patients.Add(patient);
        lstPatients.ItemsSource = null;
        lstPatients.ItemsSource = patients;         

    }


        // this.Close();
    }
```